# Pad Rows in BizTalk Flat File Schema

Tags: biztalk

I'm trying to create a BizTalk Schema that looks something like the below (ignore the spaces between the lines- they're only there for clarity.): 
"

x Rows will be inserted 
Column1^Column2^Column3^Column4^Column5
Data1a^Data2a^Data3a^Data4a^Data5a
Data1b^Data2b^Data3a^Data4b^Data5b"

So, I have a blank row, followed by a Row count, followed by a header row before I get to the actual data.  When I try to set up the schema so that the blank line (consists only of {CR}{LF}), and validate an instance, the schema fails (without an error message, to boot).

I'm running BizTalk 2009, and the file is a simple .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I found an answer:  Feel free to chime in if you find/have a better one.

Set the blank row to a Field of Type xs:string.
Set the Header row to a single record (defining the fields all as strings).
Define the repeating record.

I'm still open to further suggestions if anyone has a better way, as this seems a little clunky to me.